# Using Drawn Shapes and Changing Their Features

Tags: swift, swift3, uibezierpath

After spending a whole day trying to work out how to do it I have finally worked out a way of having non-rectangular buttons.

[image: Main Menu Design]

All three buttons at the bottom are on one button. The hitTest then works out which UIBezierPath the click was within then calls a function.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let path = UIBezierPath()
    let path2 = UIBezierPath()
    let path3 = UIBezierPath()
    let path4 = UIBezierPath()

    @IBAction func clicked(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Clicked")
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        drawShape()
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector (self.checkAction(sender:)))
        self.button.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }

    func drawShape(){
        let buttonWidth = button.frame.width
        let buttonHeight = buttonWidth * 1.23
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: buttonHeight*0.85))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: buttonHeight))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: buttonWidth, y: buttonHeight))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: buttonWidth, y: buttonHeight*0.68))
        path.close()
        path2.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: buttonHeight*0.68))
        path2.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: buttonHeight*0.85))
        path2.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: buttonWidth, y: buttonHeight*0.68))
        path2.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: buttonWidth, y: buttonHeight*0.35))
        path2.close()
        path3.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: buttonHeight*0.50))
        path3.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: buttonHeight*0.68))
        path3.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: buttonWidth, y: buttonHeight*0.35))
        path3.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: buttonWidth, y: buttonHeight*0.06))
        path3.close()
        path4.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: buttonHeight*0.45))
        path4.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: buttonHeight*0.50))
        path4.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: buttonWidth, y: buttonHeight*0.06))
        path4.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: buttonWidth, y: buttonHeight*0.01))
        path4.close()

    }

    func checkAction(sender : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let location = sender.location(in: button)
        print(location)
        hitTest(tapLocation: location)
    }

    public func hitTest(tapLocation:CGPoint){
        if path.contains(tapLocation){
            print("Button3")
        }
        if path2.contains(tapLocation){
            print("Button2")
        }
        if path3.contains(tapLocation){
            print("Button1")
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Then in the file linked to the button:

```
import UIKit
@IBDesignable

class PushButtonView: UIButton {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let buttonWidth = self.frame.width
        let buttonHeight = buttonWidth * 1.23

        let color1 = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#e0dfd5")
        let color2 = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#ef6461")
        let color3 = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#e4b363")
        let color4 = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#313638")

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: buttonHeight*0.85))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: buttonHeight))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: buttonWidth, y: buttonHeight))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: buttonWidth, y: buttonHeight*0.68))
        path.close()
        color4.setFill()
        path.fill()
        let path2 = UIBezierPath()
        path2.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: buttonHeight*0.68))
        path2.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: buttonHeight*0.85))
        path2.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: buttonWidth, y: buttonHeight*0.68))
        path2.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: buttonWidth, y: buttonHeight*0.35))
        path2.close()
        color3.setFill()
        path2.fill()
        let path3 = UIBezierPath()
        path3.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: buttonHeight*0.50))
        path3.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: buttonHeight*0.68))
        path3.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: buttonWidth, y: buttonHeight*0.35))
        path3.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: buttonWidth, y: buttonHeight*0.06))
        path3.close()
        color2.setFill()
        path3.fill()
        let path4 = UIBezierPath()
        path4.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: buttonHeight*0.45))
        path4.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: buttonHeight*0.50))
        path4.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: buttonWidth, y: buttonHeight*0.06))
        path4.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: buttonWidth, y: buttonHeight*0.01))
        path4.close()
        color1.setFill()
        path4.fill()
    }

    func hexStringToUIColor (hex:String) -> UIColor {
        var cString:String = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()

        if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
            cString.remove(at: cString.startIndex)
        }

        if ((cString.characters.count) != 6) {
            return UIColor.gray
        }

        var rgbValue:UInt32 = 0
        Scanner(string: cString).scanHexInt32(&rgbValue)

        return UIColor(
            red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
            green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
            blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
            alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
        )
    }


}
```

Everything works! It may not be the best way of doing it but after 5 hours of trying different things this is whats worked best. However I am now stuck with the problem of having no idea how to manipulate those shapes I have drawn in the external file. I am sure that this has been asked and answered before but I literally have no idea was to search for.

For example if it was javascript I would assume a 'path' drawn within the object 'button' would be accessed by self.button.path (or something similar), however, my understanding is Swift3 doesn't work like that. Am I correct? So if I wanted to change the backgroundColor of the NOTES button/shape with an animate how would I get this effect:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
    self.button.path.color = UIColor.red
}, completion: { finished in
    if(finished){
        //callFunction()
    }
})
```

Is this possible, or once a path is drawn is it not a changeable object and has to be deleted and redrawn?

Comment: You can add properties to your `PushButtonView` class to allow your view controller to modify the path color.

Comment: Amazing - so it is possible. I will start googling...

Comment: You also might be better off refactoring your `PushButtonView` to use `CAShapeLayer`s. This will give you the flexibility to animate the UI without being dependent on `drawRect`.